# Installing Spynner on Python on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, spynner

I have Python 2.7 running on Windows XP. I am trying to install Spynner as an alternative to Mechanize that supports Javascript. When I run `easy_install spynner`, I get an error while installing lxml:

`Make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxlst are installed`

Where can I find those files? I found instructions for linux but no instructions for Windows. I also tried easy_install but it could not find the packages.

Comment: Did you ever get spynner working?  I've been trying to use it for a while now, with no luck

Comment: Yes I did, by following the instructions below. Just get all of the dependencies off of pypi.python.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running Windows, try installing lxml from a precompiled binary package. [pypi.python.org](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3) hosts a [binary](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/lxml/lxml-2.3.win32-py2.7.exe) that you could use. The next run of `easy_install` should detect the new lxml distribution and the installation should work.